# Computations on algebraic numbers

Tags: c++, cgal, leda, rs, algebraic-number

I'd like to do exact computations on regular polygons. To do so, I wrote the code you find below. But the expression `cos*cos` will not compile. Apparently multiplication is not defined for the algebraic number type I'm using. I guess I'll have to try some other approach. Currently there seem to be two candidates:

1. [RS](http://www.loria.fr/equipes/vegas/rs/) apparently provides some more advanced algebraic functionality, and [CGAL has support for it](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Algebraic_kernel_d/index.html#Algebraic_kernel_dAlgebraicKernelsBasedon). But I see no multiplication operators in the related headers, so I doubt that it will do multiplication the way I'd want.
2. [leda::real](http://www.algorithmic-solutions.info/leda_manual/real.html) seems to be a type for algebraic real numbers. I'll probably have to rewrite my code, but it should be possible to achieve similar results. Perhaps I could even convert the `cos` I computed in CGAL to such a `leda::real`. The LEDA header at least appears to have an `operator*`. LEDA is free for my use but still closed source. And `leda_real.h` for CGAL 4.3 looks strange: it refers to `leda_real` not `leda::real`, so perhaps it is written for an outdated version of LEDA. And it apparently includes itself, which looks pretty pointless.

Which of these alternatives would work best for construction of an exact CGAL kernel capable of describing regular *n*-gons for arbitrary *n*? Does any of these work at all? Is there another alternative I'm missing?

Since I don't have either RS or LEDA installed on my computer, I'd prefer an educated opinion before I start building them, and perhaps even writing install instructions (“ebuilds”) for my Gentoo linux.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

//define CGAL_USE_RS
#include <CGAL/Gmpz.h>
#include <CGAL/Algebraic_kernel_d_1.h>
#include <CGAL/Algebraic_kernel_rs_gmpz_d_1.h>
#include <CGAL/Homogeneous.h>
#include <CGAL/Arr_segment_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Arrangement_2.h>

#define DBG(x) std::cerr << x << std::endl

typedef CGAL::Gmpz ZZ;
// typedef CGAL::Algebraic_kernel_rs_gmpz_d_1 AK;
typedef CGAL::Algebraic_kernel_d_1<ZZ> AK;
typedef AK::Polynomial_1 Polynomial;
typedef AK::Algebraic_real_1 AA;
typedef AK::Coefficient Coeff;
typedef AK::Bound Bound;
typedef AK::Multiplicity_type Multiplicity;
typedef CGAL::Homogeneous<AK> Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Arr_segment_traits_2<Kernel> Traits;
typedef Kernel::Point_2 Point;
typedef Kernel::Segment_2 Segment;
typedef CGAL::Arrangement_2<Traits> Arrangement;

static unsigned run(unsigned short n) {
  AK ak;
  AK::Construct_algebraic_real_1 to_AA = ak.construct_algebraic_real_1_object();
  AK::Solve_1 solve = ak.solve_1_object();
  Polynomial x{CGAL::shift(Polynomial(1), 1)}, twox{2*x};
  Polynomial a{1}, b{x};
  for (unsigned short i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
    Polynomial c = twox*b - a;
    a = b;
    b = c;
  }
  std::vector<std::pair<AA, Multiplicity>> roots;
  solve(b - 1, std::back_inserter(roots));
  AA one{1}, cos{-2};
  for (auto i = roots.begin(), e = roots.end(); i != e; ++i) {
    AA cur = i->first;
    if (cur < one && cur > cos)
      cos = cur;
  }
  AA sin = CGAL::sqrt(to_AA(1) - cos*cos);
  //DBG("sin="<<CGAL::to_double(sin)<<", cos="<<CGAL::to_double(cos));
  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
    unsigned short n;
    std::istringstream(argv[i]) >> n;
    std::cout << n << ": " << run(n) << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you sure the problem is multiplication, and not the cos() function? recall that cos(pi) = -1, and that pi is pretty irrational number.

Comment: @Cheers: `cos` is just a variable name in my case. The intention is that I compute `cos(2*pi/n)` by solving the equation `Tn(x)=1` where `Tn` is the n-th [Chebyshev polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials).

Comment: CGAL also comes with the CORE library, which might help. Last time I tried, the free version of leda didn't work at all on my machine (crash initializing the leda internal structures).

Comment: @MvG: Do you want an exact representation of cos(2*pi/n) or an approximation in `double`?

Comment: @lrineau: an exact representation.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: [`CORE::Expr`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Number_types/classCORE_1_1Expr.html) looks very promising from [what I read](http://cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/download/latest/core/doc/tutorial.pdf). Would you please turn that comment into an answer, so I can accept it once things work out as I hope they will?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CGAL also comes with the [CORE library](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Number_types/group__nt__core.html), which provide the operations you need.

Here is some code (provided by the OP himself) to compute that sin and cos exactly:

```
#include <utility>
#include <CGAL/CORE_Expr.h>
#include <CGAL/Polynomial.h>
#include <CGAL/number_utils.h>

typedef CORE::Expr AA;
typedef CGAL::Polynomial<AA> Polynomial;

// return sin(θ) and cos(θ) for θ = 2π/n
static std::pair<AA, AA> sin_cos(unsigned short n) {
  // We actually use -x instead of x since root_of will give the k-th
  // smallest root but we want the second largest one without counting.
  Polynomial x{CGAL::shift(Polynomial(-1), 1)}, twox{2*x};
  Polynomial a{1}, b{x};
  for (unsigned short i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
    Polynomial c = twox*b - a;
    a = b;
    b = c;
  }
  a = b - 1;
  AA cos = -CGAL::root_of(2, a.begin(), a.end());
  AA sin = CGAL::sqrt(AA(1) - cos*cos);
  return std::make_pair(sin, cos);
}
```

Comment: Where is the documentation of the CORE library, actually? I wonder if there exists a `solve` function for it.

Comment: I didn't look for the doc, but MvG pointed to a tutorial that has the information. Expr has a constructor that takes a polynomial and the index of the root (or an isolating interval). There is also a function rootOf.

Comment: I hope you don't mind me editing your post to provide some actual code. It seemed the best place to put this. @lrineau: [`CGALL::root_of`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Algebraic_foundations/group__PkgAlgebraicFoundations.html#ga975ad8b8b91cd67463c6c2be863d16a2) works for every [`FieldWithRootOf`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Algebraic_foundations/classFieldWithRootOf.html), and [`CORE::Expr`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Number_types/classCORE_1_1Expr.html) is a model of that concept. The above code uses that approach.